# Unable to connect because your certificate is not yet valid. Check that your system time is correct

Tags: ssh, centos, openvpn

I don't know what i did wrong. My time is correct, i even updated it from microsoft.

client config:

```
tls-client
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote xx.xxx.xxx.xxx 80
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun
comp-lzo
verb 3
reneg-sec 0
route-method exe
route-delay 2
ca ca.crt
auth-user-pass
```

Server config:

```
local xx.xxx.xxx.xxx
port 80
proto udp
dev tun
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
ca /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.crt
key /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/server.key
dh /etc/openvpn/easy-rsa/2.0/keys/dh1024.pem
plugin /usr/share/openvpn/plugin/lib/openvpn-auth-pam.so /etc/pam.d/login
client-cert-not-required
username-as-common-name
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.0.0
push "redirect-gateway def1"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
#status /etc/openvpn/logs/serverstatus-tcp.log
#log /etc/openvpn/logs/serverlog-tcp.log 
verb 3
float
duplicate-cn
#Limit server to a maximum of n concurrent clients.
max-clients 15
keepalive 20 300
```

Comment: Is the clock set correctly on the client *and* on the server?

Answer (score 4):

I had this problem too... Check and update (if necessary) the date/time on both **client** *and* **server**. In my case the server clock was NOT correct when the certificate was created. **Just correct the clock (date and time) on server, then DELETE old certificates and RE-ISSUE all certificates.**